# AWS S3 bucket returns 403 error when referencing a static folder path in Django project

Tags: javascript, css, django, amazon-web-services, bootstrap-4

I'm hosting static files in an S3 bucket for a Django web app. All has been well so far using the Appwork custom admin template: https://uxpowered.com/products/appwork/v160/

The files are rendered fine locally but unable to render from the S3 bucket. I believe the error is the script below that is referencing a folder path instead of a direct file.

```
<script>
    window.themeSettings = new ThemeSettings({
      cssPath: "{% static 'app/admin/assets/vendor/css/rtl' %}",
      themesPath: "{% static 'app/admin/assets/vendor/css/rtl' %}",
    });
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem? I confirmed the bucket folder exists and contains the correct files.

[static files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUPxX.png)
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPSVa.png)

Comment: Check read permissions of your bucket.

Comment: I updated the bucket policy at still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use access and Secret keys to fetch files from S3 bucket and use proper permissions with the user you create for the application.